# Areca Palm bottom watering question

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, watering, palm

I have read over-watering can be a problem however i haven't been able to find much of any info on bottom watering. I bottom water and things seem to be going just fine but I'm in search of a how-to wiki to know if I'm actually doing it right.
Thx

Comment: Good question; if could include current watering amount and frequency, nutrient type, amount, and frequency, soil and container details, size of your Palm, and an illustration, could also be helpful. Thank You. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Haven't had them long. Looking to establish frequency, amount, ect. Palms are about 5 ft tall. Been bottom watering about 2 inches of filtered water and adding as they drink it up.